# Setting up S3 for filepicker.io

Tags: filepicker.io

although I am pretty sure that I did everything exactly like in the video given on filepicker.io site, testing my S3 settings comes up with an error, only.

> Error in uploading: Custom S3 is not yet on. Maybe check that an ID, Key, and Bucket are all specified? Please check your settings and try again

I have double checked that the 'S3 Access Key ID' and 'S3 Secret Access Key' and 'S3 Bucket' are correct. I even created a new bucket and tried again, but to no avail. 
Here is the policy I generated for the filepicker user:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Sid": "Stmt1371459382000",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-real-name-omitted/*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

It looks a bit different from what is posted on [filepicker.io s3 help page](https://developers.filepicker.io/page/s3/) but I do not know how eliminate these differences and if it matters.

If anybody has a hint about how to fix this I'd be grateful.

Thanks in advance
Captain Fim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AWS security policy is definitely wrong - you need to allow the `PutObjectACL` action. Filepicker sets an ACL for each object it uploads. You also need to allow the `DeleteObject` action if you want to use filepicker to remove uploaded files.

You can edit your AWS security policy in the **AWS Console**. Got to **Services -> IAM -> Users** and select your filepicker user. Then select the **Permissions** tab, select the policy you are using and click **Manage Policy**. You can then manually edit the policy and apply the changes.

This is what my policy looks like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Sid": "Stmt1370702252000",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<my bucket name here>/*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

There's a **Test S3 settings** button on filepicke's S3 Settings page that might by useful as well.

Comment: Hi Annabel, thanks for the reply. I have now added "s3:DeleteObject" and "s3:PutObjectAcl" and the policy looks exactly like yours (with another Sid and Resource, naturally). But I still get the error mentioned at the beginning when clicking "Test S3 settings" on the filiepicker.io page.
There is one thing which differs from your descirption: My Policy is for a group rather than a single user, but that shouldn't make a difference, right?
Is there any other thing I can do?

Comment: This is a guess. How about your **bucket permissions**? The bucket I am using has permisions that grant **Everyone** everything - List, Upload/Delete, View. (I know this is very loose but I didn't set the bucket up!)

Comment: Now everyone may do everything on my bucket. But still I get the error. Is there anything else I could test instead of clicking the filepicker.io test button?

Comment: Oh no!!! Shame on me. I did not hit "save" next to the input fields for 'S3 Access Key ID' and 'S3 Secret Access Key'. Well, I have never seen a form where you hit 'save' for each value separately. But - looking at them now - those buttons were surely big enough. :o)